# Communication between MCU and PC - wireless

Tags: microcontroller

I am working on a project that requires me to use TI's MSP430F5529 launch pad, CC3100 Booster Pack and CC3100XX Emulator.

The project I would like to do is have the MSP430 log sensor data and to transmit it to a PC wirelessly(Without Internet). I am a beginner in using MCU,s but I can handle the datalogging part. I do not know how to get started with the communication part.

Can someone please direct me to where I could get some good reference material to get this project off the ground and if possible better insight on what I need to do to get started.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: When you say "without internet", do you mean via local network only? If so the CC3100 can be configured to work in AP mode - then the computer could  connect to that AP.